# How to create a single schema from multiple Data sources in AWS using Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I want to create a single data catalog from multiple s3 paths using AWS glue. Let’s say we have 3 s3 locations where I have my files in.

```
S3:/outbound/dir1/2023/file1.avro

S3:/outbound/dir2/2023/file2.avro

S3:/outbound/dir3/2023/file3.avro

So while configuring glue, I add 3 data sources
 
S3:/outbound/dir1/2023

S3:/outbound/dir2/2023

S3:/outbound/dir3/2023
```

Problem is, when the crawler runs, it generates one table with 2023 and two more with 2023_bxiaq12 and 2023_awqre14 (basically some hash suffix). I want to prevent that and have only one schema “2023” which has all the columns from dir1, dir2 and dir3.

Note: Each file may have a different schema structure and setting “outbound/“ as the root directory for crawling may not be ideal since it will create unnecessary tables too.

Please advise!

I tried checking “create a single schema for each s3” but it doesn’t seem to work.